# Finish some search logic

Tags: java, regex

Help me please to add some code to finish a logic. I have a some search method(public String search(String url, String someword)) which find a words in content by jsp title. So here a code

```
    String[] argi = {"http://www.google.com", "http://www.youtube.com"};

         for (int i = 0; i < argi.length; i++) {

            String result = search(argi[i], "\\b"+word+"\\b");

              if (word == null || word.isEmpty()) {

                        str = "Enter a search word!";
            }
                 else if(!word.matches("^\\w+$")){

                       str="Incorrect word!";
            }

                 else if (result != null) {

                        str += "Search phrase " + "<b>"+ word + "</b>" + " have found in " + "<a href=\"" + argi[i] + "\">" + result + "</a>"+ "<p></p>";

        }
else if  (????????) {str="Word not found!";}
        }
}
```

What should i put in last "**else if**" to get "**str="Word not found!**" if i enter to search input some normal word or digit, which is absent in content

Comment: Nothing. Just put `else`.

Comment: why not just else without condition ?

Comment: @Kiwy Possible duplicate of my comment ;)

Comment: @Maroun Maroun well mine seems to be 6 sec older than yours... so whose come first ? :D

Comment: No, it doesn't work..I tried already..Then it doesnt find any word even which present in content

Comment: @Jonny This is non sense else would matchany case the goog like the bad, and then you should be able to determine your else if value in debug mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add an other condition. However, your code can be written like this, since you don't need to put if statements about `word` inside the `for` loop:

```
String[] argi = {"http://www.google.com", "http://www.youtube.com"};
String str = "";

if (word == null || word.isEmpty()) {
    str = "Enter a search word!";
} 
else if(!word.matches("^\\w+$")) {
    str = "Incorrect word!";
}
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < argi.length; i++) {
        String result = search(argi[i], "\\b" + word + "\\b");
        if (result != null) {
            str += "Search word <b>" + word + "</b> have been found in "
                + "<a href=\"" + argi[i] + "\">" + result + "</a><br>";
        }
    }
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        str = "Word not found!";
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe last "if" you mean -  if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) ?

Comment: @Jonny: no, because if `str` is empty, it is because nothing was found and because the word is non empty and correct.

Comment: @Jonny: if you test the value of `result` here, you only test the last value of `result`. If the `word` was found in the first `argi` but not in the second, you will obtain "Word not found!"

Answer (score 2):

This block

```
else if  (????????) {str="Word not found!";}  //Remove this line
```

should be like this

move this code out of for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < argi.length; i++){
}
str="Word not found!";
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work..I tried already..Then it doesnt find any word even which present in content